# include json data in the load more button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how do i include json data in the load more button function at

> [load more button : Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yKGAc/6/)

```
    var index = 1;
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){
        var allItems = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            allItems += '<li><a href="javascript:showDetails(' + (index + i) + ')" >item number ' + (index + i) + '</a></li>';
        }        
        index += 100;

        $("#ListTemp").empty().append(allItems).listview("refresh");

        var element = $("#ListTemp li").detach();
        $("#ListDspQry").append(element);
    });   
});
```

My json url is : http://www.beritanisma.com/category/superlawak/?json=get_category_posts

been trying for days but it ended up showing no results, please help me masters, thank you..

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do

Comment: We cannot be sure of what you are asking, as it also might be an issue with **cross domain** ajax call

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: or maybe in a simpler word, i want to add load more function to my current jquery mobile json load listview content (because now it only shows 10 list and the 11th item are hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index = 0;
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){

        var url = "http://www.beritanisma.com/category/superlawak/?json=get_category_posts"

        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
           var allItems = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.posts.length; i++) {
                console.log(data.posts[i].url);
                  allItems += '<li><a href="javascript:showDetails(' + (index + i) + ')" >'+data.posts[i].url+'' + (index + i) + '</a></li>';  


            }
        index += 100;

        $("#ListTemp").empty().append(allItems).listview("refresh");

        var element = $("#ListTemp li").detach();
        $("#ListDspQry").append(element);

        });





    });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks @RexAdrivan technically you answer my question and it works great, however it doesnt really appear like i wanted it to appear. I have this list that i had sucessfully populated with json object, like shown in the image at imgur.com/0604jKc and im trying to use the code that you had fix for me and append it out like so imgur.com/w2XBn1t imgur.com/Iu8gHTe CC: DelightedD0D & dvhh

Comment: or maybe in a simpler word, i want to add load more function to my current jquery mobile json load listview content (because now it only shows 10 list and the 11th item are hidden)